# "Session terminated, terminating shell...killed"

Tags: su, debian-wheezy

I have several boxen running Debian Wheezy. They appear to have the highly annoying problem that pressing ctrl+c in a shell that has been su:d to root will kill su, not whatever is running in the root shell. This makes working with e.g. ping or tcpdump near impossible. As I understand it, the issue is debated at length in [Debian bug #628843](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=628843) but there seems to be no consensus.

```
[20:38] alias
zsu='su root -p -c $SHELL'
[20:38] zsu
Password:
zsh compinit: insecure directories and files, run compaudit for list.
Ignore insecure directories and files and continue [y] or abort compinit [n]? y
[20:38] <- I simply pressed ctrl+c
Session terminated, terminating shell...
[20:38]  ...killed.
```

I need to find a fix for this. Can I execute su differently or is there a replacement I can use instead? (Preferably no sudo and I would prefer not to allow ssh root login.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ran into the same thing as I had a similar shell alias.  I found in the manpage a "-s" option that seemed to resolve this for me:

```
   -s, --shell SHELL
       The shell that will be invoked.
```

ie:

```
zsu='su root -p -s $SHELL'
```

Comment: Much appreciated!